# How is this step done? $x\sqrt{1+{x^\prime}^2}\implies x' =\tan s$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In my notes I have a step that I don't understand:

$$x\sqrt{1+{x^\prime}^2}=\text{constant}$$
$$x' = \tan s\quad\quad\text{?????}$$

Firstly, I don't get clarification for what $s$ is. Second, how did they deduce this?

Answer (score 2):

Without further detail it is hard to answer. My *guess* is that the proffessor is trying a substitution (change-of-variables) to remove the radical sign. There is the identity $\tan^2 x +1=\sec^2 x$. Thus, the $\sqrt{1+(x')^2}\rightarrow \sec s$. The choice of variable $s$ is purely a convention that the professor wanted.